# Kubernetes pod fails with crashloopbackoff error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, repository, minikube

Created a minikube pod and downloaded an image from the hub Docker.Com private repository.

A crashloopbackoff error occurs when attempting to set up a pod to pull the image.

I want to fix this error.
How can I debug the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CrashLoopBackOff error is one of the common errors that will occur when dealing with Kubernetes deployments.

You can encounter CrashLoopBackOff error in Kubernetes pods while trying to deploy a containerized application. CrashLoopBackOff error indicates that the pod is repeatedly starting and crashing. This simply means that the pod is stuck in a crash loop.

One of the CrashLoopBackOff issues can be  caused by resource overload or insufficient memory, among other things like Misconfigurations,A resource is not available, Wrong command line arguments

**There are several steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve the issue. Here are some of    the most common fixes:**

> 1.Check the container logs:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl logs <pod-name\> <container-name\>
> ```
>
> 2 Check resource constraints:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl describe pod <pod-name\>
> ```
>
> 3 .Verify dependencies:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl exec -it <pod-name\> -c <container-name\> sh
> ```
>
> 4.Fix application errors:
>
> If the issue is related to application code, review the code to
> identify and fix any bugs or issues that may be causing the container
> to crash. You can also use tools like debuggers and profilers to help
> identify and resolve application issues.
>
> 5.Restart the container:    You can try restarting the container manually using the "kubectl  delete pod" command. This will force
> Kubernetes to create a new pod
> with a fresh container instance.
>
> ```
> $ kubectl delete pod <pod-name\>
> ```

Keep in mind that this is not a permanent solution, and the underlying issue may persist. However, it can be a useful troubleshooting step to help get your container back up and running.

These troubleshooting procedures will help you to  fix the "CrashLoopBackOff" error and restart your Kubernetes container.

Refer to this [document](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-crashloopbackoff-kubernetes-error/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Kubernetes%20CrashLoopBackOff%3F,some%20reason%2C%20then%20repeatedly%20crashes.)   by Mickael Alliel for more information about this error